# Renaming multiple different file extensions with BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to create a bash script that takes a directory full of files (about 500 files) that have all different types of extensions (no seriously, like 30 different types of extensions) and I want get rid of all of the extensions, and replace them with *.txt*

I've been searching around for a while now, and can only find examples of taking a specified extension, and changing it to another specified extension.
Like *png --> jpg*, or *.doc --> .txt*

Here's an example I've found:

```
# Rename all *.txt to *.text
for f in *.txt; do 
mv -- "$f" "${f%.txt}.text"
done
```

This works, but only if you go from *.txt* to *.text*, I have multiple different extensions I'm working with.

My current code is:

```
directory=$1
for item in $directory/*
do
echo mv -- "$item" "$item.txt";
done
```

This will append the .txt onto them, but unfortunately I am left with the previous ones still attached. E.G. *filename.etc.txt*, *filename.bla.txt*

Am I going about this wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not using regex?

Comment: my knowledge of regex is very limited, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a trivial change to the first example:

```
cd "$directory"
# Rename all files to *.txt
for f in *
do 
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}.txt"
done
```

If a file contains multiple extensions, this will replace only the last one. To remove *all* extensions, use `%%` in place of `%`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked great, but I'm not understanding whats happening inside the move function, what does the %.* do to change the situation?

Comment: Read the "Pattern Matching" section of the `bash(1)` man page or documentation.